# Plone Buildout fails cause of i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /db46: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, gcc, plone, lxml

I'm unable to complete a Plone buildout using Plone 4.3.1 R 1 (Stable) on OSX 10.6.8 cause of the following error:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
warnings.warn(msg)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'extra_require'
warnings.warn(msg)

i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /db46: No such file or directory

error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

An error occurred when trying to install lxml 3.3.1. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing lxml.
Error: Couldn't install: lxml 3.3.1
```

---

I'm using the following [versions] in by build.cfg file:

```
zc.buildout = 1.7.1
zc.recipe.egg = 1.3.2
distribute = 0.6.28
lxml = 3.3.1
```

And i already installed the following packages using the package manager "port":

```
db46 @4.6.21_9 (databases)
    The Berkeley DB package, version 4.6

db46-java @4.6.21_9 (databases)
    The Berkeley DB package, version 4.6
```

I also performed a "sudo port clean" of both packages, but gcc is still failing and complaining about a missing /db46

Does anyboady already came across this error and can help me in someway ?

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but you could try --static-lxml=no to see if that gets you any further.

Comment: Any chance you just updated to XCode 5.1 command line tools? A source of great misery.

Comment: Hi @Danimal , does this mean i have to reinstall Plone passing the option you described in the ./install.sh ? do i have to uninstall the previous installation/zinstance prior to do that ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @SteveM do you know how i can check the actual installed version of the command line tools ? I don't think i'm using the XCode 5.1, probably its an older version, and i don't have any Preferences > Download panel .. Thanks.

Comment: Yes - pass it to the install.sh. No just use a different instance name - like tmp_zinstance.  Ps I defer to SteveM on this - if anyone can get you through this it's him.

Comment: Run `gcc -v` and look at the "Apple LLVM version" to get your XCode command line tools version. If you have updated that, you'll need to rebuild all your ports and to follow Apple's instructions for setting soft warnings. "sudo port clean" by the way, does not rebuild ports, it just cleans up the detritus of old builds.